# Resolved [org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm attempting to build a twitter clone website using spring boot. I'm getting an error and looked through my code. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
2022-03-15 12:23:51.067  WARN 4580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.demo.Tweet'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'Test'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Test"]
```

This is a springboot application using postgres as its database. I also have a User repository in the code that does sign me in properly. I would appreciate any assistance with this. Thank you.

Edit: Added full stacktrace.
Edit2: Added an image of the tweeting.html to show where the string "Test" came from.

Tweet.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Entity
@Table(name="tweets")
public class Tweet {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id",unique=true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name="userid", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Integer userid;
    
    @Column(name="tweet", nullable=false)
    private String tweet;
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id; 
    }
    
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id; 
    }
    
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userid;
    }
    
    public void setUserId(Integer userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
    
    public String getTweet() {
        return tweet;
    }
    
    public void setTweet(String tweet) {
        this.tweet = tweet;
    }
    
    
}
```

TweetRepository.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TweetRepository extends JpaRepository<Tweet, Integer>{
    public Tweet findAllById(Integer userid);
}
```

TwitterController.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
public class TwitterController{
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    private TweetRepository tweetRepo;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        //model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome to spring!");
        return "index";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/testing")
    public String testing(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome to spring boot!");
        return "testing";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String signup(Model model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "register";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/tweeting")
    public String tweeting(Model model) {
        Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
        model.addAttribute("tweet", tweet);
        return "tweeting";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/process_register")
    public String processRegister(User user) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPassword = encoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        
        userRepo.save(user);
        
        return "register_success";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/process_tweet")
    public String processTweet(Tweet tweet) {
        
        tweetRepo.save(tweet);
        
        return "tweet_success";
    }
    
}
```

tweeting.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Tweet</title>
        <link href="webjars/bootstrap/5.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="container col-xl-10 col-xxl-8 px-4 py-5">
            <div class="row align-items-center g-lg-5 py-5">
              
              <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto col-lg-5">
                <form class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-3 bg-light" th:action="@{/process_tweet}" th:object="${tweet}" method="post">
                  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder=tweet th:field="*{tweet}">
                    <label for="floatingInput">Tweet</label>
                  </div>
                  
                  
                  <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-info" type="submit">Post</button>
                  
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         
         
        <script src="webjars/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="webjars/bootstrap/5.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Tweeting.html page for a better understanding on where the string "Test" came from.]

Comment: Could you give us the full stacktrace?

Comment: Added the full stacktrace.

Comment: thats part of the startup process logs. Show use the ERROR stacktrace. Theres nothing below this line? `2022-03-15 12:23:51.067  WARN 4580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.demo.Tweet'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'Test'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: `

Comment: `NumberFormatException: For input string: "Test"` - Where did "Test" come from and why are you trying to convert it to a number?  Start with that.

Comment: There is nothing else below the message after java.lang.NumberFormatException.

As for where "Test" comes from that string comes from, the input I did in the tweeting.html page.